# Rotated text inside div overlaps

Tags: html, css, sass

So I will try my best to explain the situation here.
I want to rotate some text inside a div without letting its edges to show outside the div. I want something like in the attached image: [image: result image]

What I am currently getting is something like this: [image: current]

```
<aside>
    <h2>Greeting<p>s</p></h2>
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      </p>
    </div>
  </aside>

aside{
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: rgba(151, 0, 0, 0.76);
  height: 71.3em;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;

  h2{
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
    position: relative;
    top: 1em;
    font-size: 2em;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    &:first-letter{
      font-size: 3em;
    }
    p{
      display: inline;
      font-size: 2em;
    }
  }

  .text{
    position:relative;
    top: 3em;

    p{
      font-size: 2em;
      color: black;
      font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
      transform: rotate(15deg);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could use skew instead :
(for a 90degrees rotation, there is [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) for that purpose, unfornately, it won't do here)

```css
aside {
  width: 20%;
  min-width:20em;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: rgba(151, 0, 0, 0.76);
  height: 71.3em;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
aside h2 {
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  position: relative;
  top: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(0, 15deg);
}
aside h2:first-letter {
  font-size: 3em;
}
aside h2 p {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 2em;
}
aside .text {
  position: relative;
  top: 3em;
}
aside .text p {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Kaushan Script', cursive;
  transform: skew(0, 15deg);
}
```

```html
<aside>
    <h2>Greeting<p>s</p></h2>
    <div class="text">
      <p>
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
      </p>
    </div>
  </aside>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqBymr

Comment: man you saved my day, thanks a lot!, didn't know about skew, its pretty cool shit